# Write/store dataframe in text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to write `dataframe` to `text` file. If a file contains single column then I am able to write in text file. If file contains multiple column then I a facing some error

> Text data source supports only a single column, and you have 2
>   columns.

```
object replace {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("Decimal Field Validation").getOrCreate()

    var sourcefile = spark.read.option("header","true").text("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/inputfiles/decimalvalues.txt")

     val rowRDD = sourcefile.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(indexedRow => Row.fromSeq((indexedRow._2.toLong+1) +: indexedRow._1.toSeq)) //adding prgrefnbr               
                         //add column for prgrefnbr in schema
     val newstructure = StructType(Array(StructField("PRGREFNBR",LongType)).++(sourcefile.schema.fields))

     //create new dataframe containing prgrefnbr

     sourcefile = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, newstructure)
     val op= sourcefile.write.mode("overwrite").format("text").save("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/op")

  }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can convert the dataframe to rdd and covert the row to string and write the last line as

```
 val op= sourcefile.rdd.map(_.toString()).saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/op")
```

**Edited**

As @philantrovert and @Pravinkumar have pointed that the above would append `[` and `]` in the output file, which is true. The solution would be to `replace` them with `empty` character as

```
val op= sourcefile.rdd.map(_.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "")).saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/op")
```

One can even use `regex`

Comment: I think this will add `[` and `]` at both ends of each row.

Comment: but its adding "[ ]" to each record for each line.eg:[2,12.2,12.2]

Comment: yes it does you can replace it with empty. let me update the answer

Comment: yes I am able to read but "EURO' sign reading as a garbej value.input value = €|€,output value= "�|�". after conversion

Comment: I am guessing its a serialization and deserialization issue . This can be another question in SO . What do you say @PravinkumarHadpad?

Comment: Yes Ramesh but I dont have access to raise one more question. I have limit of 2 question per week. Thats great help if you suggest something.

Comment: I just tested by putting `€` symbol in input file and it came to output without problem. How are you viewing the file? can you see the symbol in your input file?

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan, I saw this question just to verify my answer to a problem. my answer is almost similar but I used  "substring" instead "replace". please see my answer below. please let me know is there any practical problem if we use like below.

Comment: Using `replace` could cause issues if the string itself has those characters. We can use `.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]")` to remove only the leading and trailing brackets.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using a `csv` or other delimited formats. The following is an example with the most **concise/elegant** way to write to .tsv in Spark 2+

```
val tsvWithHeaderOptions: Map[String, String] = Map(
  ("delimiter", "\t"), // Uses "\t" delimiter instead of default ","
  ("header", "true"))  // Writes a header record with column names

df.coalesce(1)         // Writes to a single file
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .options(tsvWithHeaderOptions)
  .csv("output/path")
```

Comment: This does not write a tsv file but a csv

Comment: NOTE the `"delimiter", "\t"` option. It should work (works for me)

Comment: I have exactly the same code in Spark 2.4 and it writes a CSV. Moreover, I did not find a solution to this.

Comment: Works for me in 2.3. I wonder if something else is going on here though...

Answer (score 2):

You can save as text *CSV* file (`.format("csv")`)

The result will be a text file in a CSV format, each  column will be separated by a comma.

```
val op = sourcefile.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/op")
```

More info can be found in the [spark programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Comment: I want file extension should be .txt by above solution  file extension is .csv

Comment: How do you want each row to be printed? Comma-separated or something else?

Comment: @PravinkumarHadpad - why do you care if the output file extension is .txt or .csv?

Comment: its appending double quotes for the values available in dataframes before adding seq number.eg:- 3,"12.20,12.2-" but I want output file data like 3,12.20,12.2

Comment: basically I want double quotes free out file thats why I want to store it in text file.

Answer (score 2):

I think using "substring" is more appropriate for all scenarios I feel.

Please check below code.

```
sourcefile.rdd
.map(r =>  { val x = r.toString; x.substring(1, x.length-1)})
.saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/phadpa01/Desktop/op")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use databricks api to save my DF output into text file.

```
myDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("output.csv")
```