# How to save DataFrame output in PySpark to a TextFile?

Tags: pyspark

I have a DataFrame (table) below and I am using sum function on columns _3 and _4.

```
df.show()
+---------+------+---+---+
|       _1|    _2| _3| _4|
+---------+------+---+---+
| playerID|yearID| HR|RBI|
|aardsda01|  2004|  0|  0|
|aardsda01|  2006|  0|  0|
|aardsda01|  2007|  0|  0|
|aardsda01|  2008|  0|  0|
|aardsda01|  2009|  0|  0|
|aardsda01|  2010|  0|  0|
|aaronha01|  1954| 13| 69|
|aaronha01|  1955| 27|106|
|aaronha01|  1956| 26| 92|
|aaronha01|  1957| 44|132|
|aaronha01|  1958| 30| 95|
|aaronha01|  1959| 39|123|
|aaronha01|  1960| 40|126|
|aaronha01|  1961| 34|120|
|aaronha01|  1962| 45|128|
|aaronha01|  1963| 44|130|
|aaronha01|  1964| 24| 95|
|aaronha01|  1965| 32| 89|
|aaronha01|  1966| 44|127|
+---------+------+---+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I want to store the output of the following to a TextFile.

```
df.agg({'_3':'sum','_4':'sum'}).show()
+--------+---------+                                                            
| sum(_3)|  sum(_4)|
+--------+---------+
|264983.0|1642662.0|
```

Comment: save where? to a file? to a database? to a variable?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions

Comment: I just want to save below output as a textfile--------+---------+                                                            
| sum(_3)|  sum(_4)|
+--------+---------+
|264983.0|1642662.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write/store dataframe in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537889/write-store-dataframe-in-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a duplicate.

You can use the databricks format to save the output as a text file:

```
myDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("output.csv")
```

In your case you can use:

```
df.agg({'_3':'sum','_4':'sum'}).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("output.csv")
```